# How to get the content of the file that the user has uploaded in the form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form where the user can upload a file. The file should not be stored in my database.I want to view the contents of a file and then return a response to the user.How can i get the content. If I call by name, it just returns the file name.

```
  <input type="file" required class="form-control" accept=".xml"id="file" name="file" multiple>
```

```
 public function loadData(Request $req) {

        dd($req->input('file'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the contents of the file uploaded using file_get_contents() method. Example:

```
file_get_contents($request->file);
```

Comment: Don't work, return 'Failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

Comment: Let's validate the if the file is valid or not. 
`dd($request->file->isValid()); `
if it gives you true then it must work, otherwise there must be issue with the uploaded file. 
And one more thing, please make sure you are submitting multipart/formdata.

Comment: thanks, I didn't write multipart/formdata.

Answer (score 1):

From [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files):

> You may retrieve uploaded files from an Illuminate\Http\Request
> instance using the file method or using dynamic properties. The file
> method returns an instance of the Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile class,
> which extends the PHP SplFileInfo class and provides a variety of
> methods for interacting with the file.

```php
public function loadData(Request $req)
{
    $content = $req->file('file')->get();
}
```